# Regex optional character preceded by Negative Lookback in R

Tags: r, regex, regex-lookarounds, grepl

Suppose I have a set of strings:

```
test <- c('MTB', 'NOT MTB', 'TB', 'NOT TB')
```

I want to write a regular expression to match either 'TB' or 'MTB' (e.g., the expression "M?TB") strictly when this FAILS to be preceeded by the phrase "NOT " (space included).

My intended result, therefore, is

`TRUE  FALSE  TRUE  FALSE`

So far I have tried a couple of variations of

```
grepl("(?<!NOT )M?TB", test, perl = T)
```

`TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE`

Unsuccessfully. As you can see, the phrase 'NOT MTB' meets the criteria for my regular expression.

It seems like including the optional character "M?" seems to make R think that the negative lookbehind is also optional. I have been looking into using parentheses to group the patterns, such as

```
grepl("(?<!NOT )(M?TB)")
```

`TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  FALSE`

Which also fails to exclude the phrase 'NOT MTB'.  Admittedly, I am unclear on how parentheses work in regex or eeven what "grouping" means in this context.  I have had trouble finding a question related to how to group, require, and "optionalize" different parts of a regex so that I can match a phrase ***beginning with an optional character and preceeded by a negative lookback***.  What is the proper way to write an expression like this?

Comment: why not simply use `^MTB|TB' for regex `?` means a single character to be matched. This will not match `NOT MTB` I believe too.

Comment: Please clarify 2 things: 1) Can you have `THIS MTB` value that you would like to get? 2) What if there are two or more spaces between `NOT` and `TB`, do you need to handle those cases?

Comment: I hope my example hasn't distracted from the question.  The question is to write a regex that matches "M?TB" with the additional criterion of the negative lookback "(?<!NOT\\s).  The "domain" of this problem could reasonably be "THIS MBT" or "WHY IS THIS NOT MTB" or any arbitrary number of other possibilities, but these are beside the point. I want to match the phrase "M?TB" while excluding "NOT M?TB"

Answer (score 2):

We could use the start (`^`) and end (`$`) to match  only those words

```
grepl("^M?TB$", test)
#[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

---

If there are other strings as @Wiktor Stribiżew mentioned in the comments, then one option would be

```
test1 <- c(test, "THIS MTB")
!grepl("\\bNOT M?TB\\b", test1) & grepl("\\bM?TB\\b", test1)
#[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: I think it makes sense to also use word boundaries in `"NOT M?TB"`. Another option is to use a negative lookahead (anchored at the start) check with a greedy dot and `"\\bM?TB\\b"` in the consuming part, but it will already be a PCRE regex (`perl=TRUE`)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  Thanks, you are the God of regex, I won't argue with you :=)

Answer (score 2):

```
test = c("MTB", "NOT MTB", "TB", "NOT TB", "THIS TB", "THIS NOT TB")

grepl("\\b(?<!NOT\\s)M?TB\\b",test,perl = TRUE)

[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: Hi @Onyambu.  Your suggestion seems to work for my example and seems to be exactly what I was looking for.  Could you explain a bit further the purpose of the leading and trailing "\\b" additions?  Including them causes my statement to work, but I don't understand why.

Comment: @G.Vece the `\\b` matches the boundary of the word. ensuring that the pattern only matches the words with a boundary and not one without

Answer (score -1):

There is some question on what the question intends but here is some code to try depending on what is wanted.

Added: Poster clarified that #2 and #3 are along the lines looked for.

**1)** This can be done without regular expressions like this:

```
test %in% c("TB", "MTB")
## [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

**2)** If the problem is not about exact matches then return matches to M?TB which do not also match NOT M?TB:

```
grepl("M?TB", test) & !grepl("NOT M?TB",test)
## [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

**3)** Another alternative is to replace NOT M?TB with X and then grepl on M?TB:

```
grepl("M?TB", sub("NOT M?TB", "X", test))
## [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: Are you sure? What if `THIS MTB` should also be returned?

Comment: Quite on the contrary. The whole question is about checking for `NOT` before `TB` or `MTB`.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  #1 answers a different question since I intentionally did not specify that I'm looking for an exact match.  I'm looking for a regex solution that matches "M?TB" while excluding "NOT M?TB" regardless of additional trailing or leading text.  #2 is certainly a solution and in fact is what I'm currently using, but I really would like to learn regex better and this seems like a good case for a negative lookbehind,  Same for #3